# Delete Prefixes of JPG names till '_'-symbol in POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell, split, duplicates, jpeg, file-rename

Good day!

We have folder with many JPG-files which named in the following format: "1_abcd_0000.jpg", "12_defg_0001.jpg", "123_ghij_0002.jpg".

I need to cut 1-st part of these names till 1-st split "_"-symbol included.

My code is:

> $DirRank=New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,int]'
> $mainfolder="C:\Users"
> Get-ChildItem $mainfolder | %{Rename-Item $*.fullname $*.Name.Split("_")[1]} //here is a mistake

Here are 2 problems after code running:

1. Names of files cut till the last split "_"-symbol, instead of 1-st one; new format of files is "0001", "0002", ect.;
2. New files can't be saved in bulk because of duplicates of names.

Please help to correct code to rename files.

Thanks!

> $DirRank=New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,int]'
> $mainfolder="C:\Users"
> Get-ChildItem $mainfolder | %{Rename-Item $*.fullname $*.Name.Split("_")[1]} //here is a mistake

Answer (score 1):

This regex repaces everything up to the first LOW LINE (underscore). The QUESTION MARK causes it not to be greedy.

```
$_.Name -replace '^.*?_(.*)','$1'
```

This will not fix the problem of duplicate file names. What are your business rules when a duplicate name would be created?

Comment: I understand that and the code in the answer will remove the prefix. What needs to happen when this results in a filename that already exists?

Comment: We have photos renamed in bulk with prefixes. 
Now we need to load photos in web-storage to create link on photo by unique code without 1-st prefix (numbers till  "_"-symbol).
The main idea is that we could check the photo of current item before send order to client.
The main problem is prefix in name - item numbers are unique, if we cut prefixes, there will be not duplicates.

Comment: Does removing the prefix have a possibility of creating a duplicate filename as specified in the question? `"New files can't be saved in bulk because of duplicates of names.
"`

Comment: I described situation of my code: my version deleted all symbols till the last LOW LINE and saved format as last counter 0001, 0002, ect.

Comment: One more question: if we need to delete LOW LINE too, why QUESTION SIGN shall be placed before LOW LINE, but not after it? 

 $_.Name -replace '^.*_?(.*)','$1'

Comment: The QUESTION MARK charaacter is placed after the optional item. Reed about regex greed at https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html